# Why does my Or statement mess up my programming?

Tags: python, if-statement, authentication, logic, logical-operators

users = {}
status = ""

def Menu():
global status
status = input("Are you a registered user Y/N? Enter q to quit. \n")

```
if status == "Y" or "y":  #I wanted to make the option do capital and lowercase Y and N but when I
    OldUser()
elif status == "N" or "n":  #enter "n" it goes to OldUser() instead of Register()
    Register()
```

def Register():
name = input("Enter a username: ")

```
if name in users:
    print("The username is already used. Try again.")
else:
    pass_w = input("Enter a password: ")
    users[name] = pass_w
    print("\n Registration Complete! \n")
```

def OldUser():
login_n = input("Enter your username: ")

```
if login_n in users:
    login_p = input("Enter your password: ")

    if login_p == users[login_n]:
        print("\n Login Successful! \n")
    else:
        print("Password incorrect!")
else:
    print("\n Wrong user or user doesn't exist. \n")
```

while status != "q":
Menu()

Comment: additionally you can add a .lower() or .upper() to the end of your variable so userInput = input('Enter y or n').lower() and then your if statement just use lowercase y and even if they use and uppercase letter itll convert it too a lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
if status == "Y" or status == "y": 
    OldUser()
elif status == "N" or status == "n":  
    Register()
```

And their is another better solution to do it like this:

```
if status.lower() == "y": 
    OldUser()
elif status.lower() == "n":  
    Register()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if status in ["Y", "y"]:  
    OldUser()
elif status in ["N", "n"]:  
    Register()
```

or you can use

```
if status  == "Y" or  status  == "y":  
    OldUser()
elif status ==  "N" or  status  =="n":  
    Register()
```

or you can lower status and do this

```
if status.lower() ==  "y":  
    OldUser()
elif status.lower() ==  "n":  
    Register()
```